# Добавить класс к нечетному элементу списка

Tags: jquery

Всем доброй ночи, Ребят вот такой вопрос как добавить класс нечетному элементу,
Допустим есть 
Блок id в нем

1. <четный>
2. <нечетный> - как этому тегу дать
       класс
3. <четный>
4. <нечетный> - как этому тегу дать
       класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все разобрался, покапался в доках.
Если комуто понадобиться вот ссылка: [Селектор по классу](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Селектор_по_классу)

```
$("#Список .Классы в спеке:odd").addClass("black");
```